# Redundant Sparse (3NF) Data Structure

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

Given the following table of events:

```py
+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| Case ID | Activity ID | Resource | Firm     | Timestamp |
+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| 1       | A           | Alice    | BMW      | 20:21     |
+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| 1       | B           | Bob      | BMW      | 20:24     |
+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| 2       | A           | Alice    | Mercedes | 10:45     |
+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| 2       | C           | Bob      | Mercedes | 11:23     |
+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| 3       | B           | Alice    | Mercedes | 11:00     |
+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| 3       | C           | Bob      | Mercedes | 23:45     |
+---------+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

we can observe that if we group the entries by the `Case ID`, we would end up with information specific to each `Case ID` (e.g. `Firm`), as well as information specific to each event (e.g. `Activity ID`, `Resource`, `Timestamp`).

Storing it all in the current table, repeats the values `BMW` and `Mercedes` at least once. Now for datasets with a lot of events per `Case ID`, we would have a lot more redundant information.

What I would like is a sort of sparse representation of this table, where I don't store the duplicates, but maybe only reference them. I would still like to keep the filtering, and sorting capabilities that for example a full table such as pandas' data frame brings.

My question is, if there is an already established in-memory data-structure and/or library that already implements something like this. Maybe pandas already does this, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Thanks for any help or pointers.

**UPDATE 1**

As @HighPerformanceMark pointed out, you could formulate my requirement as a data structure similar to a set of 3 tables. One for attributes specific to the `Case ID`, another one for the attributes specific to the events, and lastly a table mapping the keys from the former to the latter.

My original question still stays: is there already an efficient data-structure I could implement or is there a library for my use case. If I would take a wild guess, I could imagine a combination of 3 pandas data-structures, used as described in the previous paragraph, though I am not really sure how efficiently I could perform the previous mentioned my operations (filtering).

Comment: When string column has many repeating values then converting column to category type saves memory usage:  `df.mycolumn.astype('category')`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I guess you could formulate it as that. If you have a table for attributes specific to the `Case ID`, another one for the event specific attributes and a table mapping the keys from one table to another.

Comment: @ipj that I didn't know, thank you. Does this generalise also to non-string attributes such as `datetime` values?

Comment: Yes, if date values are repeating then memory usage will be also reduced. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html